# How to post select tag value into PHP using Ajax post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have these HTML select code.

```
<div>
    <select id="pickType" class="form-control select2 " name="pickType">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Type</option>
        <option value="TBL_LEMON">Lemon</option>
        <option value="TBL_APPLE">Apple</option>
        <option value="TBL_GRAPE">Grape</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And I use Ajax serialize to post the data into php file (populate.php). The jQuery code as below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pickType').change(function(){

            var selected = $(this).val();
            var data_type = $("#pickType").serialize()+"&type="+"getTable";
            $.post("populate.php",data_type).done(function( data ){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(selected);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the value cannot be sent into populate.php, therefore PHP file cannot pass the json data back.

I tried to console.log and alert the value and it works fine.

My goal is to pass the value from select into my SQL Query. Because my SQL Query will have to query 3 different table. The code for my PHP as below.

```
if((isset($_POST['type'])) && ($_POST['type']=='getTable'))
{
    $sql = DB::getInstance()->FetchArray("select * from '".$_POST['pickType']."' ");
    if(count($sql) > 0)
    {
        $array  = array();
        foreach($sql as $row)
        {
            $array2 = array();
            $array2[]= $row['ID'];
            $array2[]= $row['SUBJECT_ITEMS'];
            $array[] =  $array2;
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here ?

Appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: in your php file var_dump($_POST['pickType']) what gives you?

Comment: Nothing be sent into php file.  empty and no errors on both side. I also confuse.

Comment: Because i tried the same concept, i use onclick function, it works fine. But didn't work on select change function.

Comment: try to console.log(data_type ) before $.post() function

Comment: It shows "{pickType:"TBL_LEMON", type: "getTable"}
pickType: "TBL_LEMON"
type: "getTable"
__proto__: Object"

Comment: Opps, sorry. here's the console.log . "pickType=TBL_LEMON&type=getTable"

Comment: in your php file try only if($_POST['type']=='getTable'){}

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code

```
var data_type = $("#pickType").serialize()+"&type="+"getTable";
```

to follow code

```
var data_type = {
  pickType: selected,
  type: 'getTable'
}
```

Comment: Try check "populate.php" whether you passed the correct url

Comment: Already tried it. No value were passed into php file using change function. but function onclick works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val();
var data_type = "pickType="+selected+"&type=getTable";
```

also you can check your post data in the params tab under the network section of the browsers developer console to make sure the data is being posted

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use ajax call. First of all get the value of selected option:

```
var selectedOpt = $('#pickType').val();
```

and then call your **populate.php** using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'populate.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
          'type': selectedOpt,
          'pickType': 'getTable'
           },
     success: function(result){
     }
});
```

also I think you have wrong post keys in your php file:

```
if((isset($_POST['type'])) && ($_POST['type']=='getTable'))
```

maybe should be

```
  if((isset($_POST['pickType'])) && ($_POST['type']=='getTable'))
```

Comment: Already tried your suggestion on first try. but no value were sent into populate.php. It works fine on click function but didn't work on change select function. weird.

Comment: have you checked your $_POST keys? There is a two 'type'-s

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that I add a single quote on name of table in populate.php

It should be ".$_POST['pickType']." , so the query will be **"select * from TBL_LEMON"**.

My problem above because I added single quote '".$_POST['pickType']."' , the query failed because **"select * from 'TBL_LEMON' "**

My problem solved. Thanks.